# How can I do a redirect from a qr code to a page within my app with flutter?

Tags: javascript, android, flutter, dart

the user when reading the qrcode, he should be redirected to an internal page that is hidden, he could only be redirected through this link

I tried using some libs like https://pub.dev/packages/qr_code_scanner but it doesn't do what I wan

Comment: include the snippet of code you're using that package

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

It worked, I passed a `Get.toName('pageName')`;